# Allow for different customer to pay for a Stripe Subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working with Stripe to manage subscriptions. I would like to delegate payment of a subscription to another customer.

Specifically, I want the customer of the subscription to reap the benefits of a subscription, but assign another customer to pay for it.

Is that possible? If not, what are the possible workarounds? Thanks.

Notes:

1. Once a subscription is created, an invoice is automatically generated and is not editable according to what I have tried previously
2. I would like to keep as close to the usual subscription flows as possible, as I don't want to lose out on things such as being able to pro-rate an invoice (which becomes messy if I have to manually craft invoices myself)

Comment: I'd think you'd handle this at your application level, by having something like a `paid_by` column referencing the other user.

Comment: Thanks @Ceejayoz but as you can imagine, it's never as simple as that :) For example, a subscription when created automatically created an invoice. We could create that subscription for £0 but then we would have to work out pro-rating ourselves etc and we couldn't adjust prices from within stripe easily. Alternatively we could create the sub and invoice and pay it with a voucher, and create a new bespoke invoice for the delegate, which is current best solution, but that still involves creating bespoke invoices.

Comment: I'm not understanding your objection. Create the subscription under the paying customer. Save that subscription ID to the non-paying customer's record. Look up that subscription ID via the API when you need to present information about it or validate its existence. Doesn't matter who owns it under the hood.

Comment: Thanks again @Ceejayoz. It's not clear in my question, but it does matter under the hood as there is a one-to-one relationship between a user and a subscription currently. I've tried to keep the question brief and focused but a large part of our current code implementation relies on the fact that there is a 1:2:1 relationship between our user and a stripe subscription. We could of course change that, but I'd like to exhaust alternative options first.